# ЭЦП расшифровка ответ ФСС ЭЛН .Net

Tags: c#, x509certificate, decrypt

Возникла проблема интеграции с ЭЛН ФСС. Использую КриптоПро для подписи запроса. Скопировал контейнер Рутокен в реест. Оттуда установил сертификат личный. Пример взял с SDK подписания, подпись проходит, проверка успешна, отправляю зашифрованный запрос на сервис:

```
public void SendFss()
{
    string oRequest = "";

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("c_encrypted.xml");
    oRequest = doc.OuterXml;

    //Builds the connection to the WebService.
    HttpWebRequest req =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://docs.fss.ru/WSInsurerCrypto/FileOperationsLnPort?WSDL");
    req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://ru/ibs/fss/ln/ws/FileOperationsLn.wsdl/getPrivateLNData\"");
    req.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"";
    req.Accept = "text/xml";
    req.Method = "POST";

    //Passes the SoapRequest String to the WebService
    using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
        {
            stmw.Write(oRequest);
        }
    }
    //Gets the response
    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    //Writes the Response
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);

    string str = sr.ReadToEnd();

    File.WriteAllText("resp_txt.xml", str);
}
```

Где `c_encrypted` зашифрованный запрос. Ответ приходит от от сервиса и пытаюсь его расшифровать:

```
public void Decrypt(string xmlFile="resp_txt.xml")
{
    XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    //xd.PreserveWhitespace = false;
    xd.Load(xmlFile);
    EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml(xd);
    exml.DecryptDocument()
}
```

И на `DecryptDocument` возникает ошибка:

> Не удается извлечь ключ дешифрования.

Как сделать правильно дешифрование?

Comment: А вы при расшифровке никакие ключи не указываете. Это как-то странно выглядит.

Comment: @ArchDemon по-идее, они должны взяться из сертификата, который лежит в ответном xml

Comment: Хм, а где логика? Если я получу ваш ответ, то я могу его расшифровать даже если не знаю никаких ключей?

Comment: В ответном сообщении мой сертификат, он у меня установлен и привязан к контейнеру который у меня в реестре (КриптоПро -> посмотреть по сертификату контейнер, отображается нормально).  Не понимаю как указать при расшифровке каким ключом дешифровать. Пробовал добавлять CspParameter где указывал имя контейнера в реестре- никаких эмоций

Comment: @ProgRB автор будьте любезны посмотреть мой ответ и хотябы комментнуть туда, что остается непонятным для дешифровки.

Answer (score 1):

Объяснять долго и мучительно, установите Crypto .NET SDK, у них есть примеры. Вам нужен пример EncryptCerts:

```
C:\Program Files\Crypto Pro\.NET SDK\Examples\simple.zip\Xml\cs\EncryptCerts.cs
```

Пишу дополнение к тому примеру, который и так комментирован на русском (пример для нескольких шифрованных узлов, я напишу для 1):

- Расшифрование Xml документа на ключе из сертификата
- Создаем объект `XmlDocument`.
- Загружаем XML данные в объект `XmlDocument` (ну тут у кого как делается). У автора из файла.
- Ищем узел с зашифрованными данными, а именно узел `"EncryptedData"`.
- Преобразуем узел `XmlNode` в `XmlElement` (`XmlElement element = node as XmlElement;`)
- Создаем объект `EncryptedData` (`EncryptedData encryptedData = new EncryptedData();`)
- Загружаем в него элемент с зашифрованными данными (`encryptedData.LoadXml(element);`)
- Теперь надо инициализировать экземпляр сертификата содержащего приватный ключ для дешифровки (автор должен знать где этот сертификат у него лежит и как его получить, рас он шифровать умеет).
- Необходимо получить "ключ" дешифровки (все таки придется почитать пример).
- Дешифруем данные (`byte[] decryptedData = exml.DecryptData(encryptedData, decryptionKey);`)
- Заменяем в XML документе зашифрованный узел, на дешифрованные данные (`exml.ReplaceData(element, decryptedData);`)

PS: так яснее стало ?
PSPS: автор и так пользовался этими примерами, просто взял для себя неподходящий, надо было чуток дальше посмотреть по списку. Ему ответ понятен ? - тогда ответ хороший.

Comment: ИМХО, слишком общий ответ, не дает понимания ответа ни тому, кто спрашивает, ни тому, кто будет искать ответ на данный вопрос в дальнейшем

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov а вы хотите чтобы я сюда запихнул мозги и код в 300 строк ? Я дал конкретное место где есть 100% ответ на данный вопрос по дешифрованию (что установить, где там находится пример). Сами пробовали читать и сравнивать как дешифрует автор вопроса и как это происходит в том примере ?